# Invalid characters appearing at random in XML output, including within the tags

Tags: php, xml

I have a php script which generates an XML document, however there is a strange problem with the output.

I'm getting invalid characters seemingly at random throughout the document, even in the tags themselves? For example:

```
<id><![CATA[JS-DWLG001]]></id>
```

I'm not sure how this will render in your browser, so if you can't see it, the invalid character is replacing the 'D' in 'CDATA'.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the business bit of the code to generate the xml:

```
<?
// variables and arrays populated here from db
?>

<job>
                <title><![CDATA[<?=$field['vac_Title']?>]]></title>
                <date><![CDATA[<?=date("D, j M Y g:i:s",$stamp)." GMT"?>>]]></date>
                <referencenumber><![CDATA[<?=$field['vac_Ref']?>]]></referencenumber>
                <url><![CDATA[<?=site_URL.parse_job_path($field['vac_Title'],$key)?>]]></url>
                <company><![CDATA[<?=$field['vac_advertiser_name']?>]]></company>
                <city><![CDATA[]]></city>
                <state><![CDATA[<?=$field['vac_locs']?>]]></state>
                <country><![CDATA[UK]]></country>
                <postalcode><![CDATA[]]></postalcode>
                <description><![CDATA[<?=$field['vac_Description']?>]]></description>
                <salary><![CDATA[<?-$field['vac_Salary-Range']?>]]></salary>
                <education><![CDATA[<?=$education_level?>>]]></education>
                <jobtype><![CDATA[<?=$emp_type?>]]></jobtype>
                <category></category>
                <experience></experience>
            </job>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of the php script?

Comment: You posted the error on ID and the field ID is not in the other bit...

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that we have five different scripts which generate slightly different XML output but all similar to the above. The invald characters are appearing in the output of all five files, seemingly at random as described. I just gave the 'id' line originally as an example of how the character appears actually within the XML tags, not just in the data they contain.

Comment: It's going to be tough for people to help you with this one. It's a needle-in-a-haystack problem; if you knew where to look, you could find it easily, but you don't, and you can't post the whole haystack for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In php scripts it normally create problems when we try to generate XML with appending strings. Your output may have some special and unicode characters. So its always a good idea to use libraries provided by core php. Like you can use DOM XML for XML generation. This will handle your special characters and format too.
Here is the sample code with DOM XML

```
<?php
$books = array();
$books [] = array(
    'title' => 'PHP Hacks',
    'author' => 'Jack Herrington',
    'publisher' => "O'Reilly"
    );

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$r = $doc->createElement( "books" );
$doc->appendChild( $r );

foreach( $books as $book )
{
    $b = $doc->createElement( "book" );

    $author = $doc->createElement( "author" );
    $author->appendChild(
        $doc->createTextNode( $book['author'] )
        );
    $b->appendChild( $author );

    $title = $doc->createElement( "title" );
    $title->appendChild(
        $doc->createTextNode( $book['title'] )
        );
    $b->appendChild( $title );

    $publisher = $doc->createElement( "publisher" );
    $publisher->appendChild(
        $doc->createTextNode( $book['publisher'] )
        );
    $b->appendChild( $publisher );

    $r->appendChild( $b );
}
header('Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8');

echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Hope this will fix your issue